# How long does the zombie of a previous survivor last?

Tags: zombiu

I managed to lose my first survivor right at the end of the first mission, where you need to go to the supermarket. Upon spawning I was thrown right into a new mission where I needed to defend the safe house. I wasn't able leave the safe house until I completed the mission, and manage to lose a few survivors in the process. When I returned to the location of my death afterwards, I was unable to locate the Zombie of my first survivor. I'm assuming the game only keeps the Zombies of one or two survivors around, and so that survivor just despawned.

How many survivor Zombies will be kept alive by the game at one time? Are there any other factors which decide whether or not a Survivor Zombie will spawn?

Comment: Technically the game doesn't keep the survivor Zombies alive... because they are dead ;p

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the game only keeps your very last zombified survivor around. If your current survivor gets zombified before you're able to find and loot your previous incarnation, your previous zombie - and its loot - are gone forever.

This can be quite frustrating if that survivor was carrying some good loot (I lost the carbine rifle before I could even shoot it once this way…), but that adds a strategy element to the game; ideally your current survivor should be carrying as little as possible, and anything you might need later should be stored in one of the storage boxes (such as the one by the computer in the subway station at the beginning of the game) or simply not picked up at all yet. But how do you know what you might need later before you need it? Yep… it's a tough game.